# Node.js : Array attribute of an object is undefined but in fact have values

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

It's been two days that I've been looking into this error. This is on MEVN stack (MySQL, Express, VueJS, NodeJS). There an object which I called contract which have a bunch of attributes including an array containing my account managers IDs. When I try to access or log it directly I get an undefined, but when I console.log the whole object I can clearly see that the array is here and have values. I don't get why I can't access it like other attributes.

Here, first, you can find a screenshot of my browser console showing that the object contains an array but when I access the array I get an undefined.
[image]

Here is the code which I run which is in the methods block in VueJS.

```
if(contractsList.length > 0){
    console.log("contractsList")
    console.log(contractsList)
    for(let contract of contractsList){
      //Set society name
      contract.society_name = this.getSocietyName(contract.society_id)
      //Set commercial and account managers names (firstname + lastname)
      contract.commercial_name = contract.commercial_id != null ? this.getUserName(contract.commercial_id) : " "
      let account_manager_avatars = []
      console.log("contract")
      console.log(contract)
      console.log("contract.account_managers")
      console.log(contract.account_managers)
      console.log(typeof contract.account_managers)
      if(contract.account_managers && contract.account_managers.length > 0){
        for(let collaborator in contract.account_managers){
          console.log("collaborator")
          console.log(collaborator)
          account_manager_avatars.push({
            name: this.getUserName(collaborator),
            users_id: collaborator
          })
        }
      }
      //Set account managers avatars
      contract.account_manager_avatars = account_manager_avatars.length > 0 ? account_manager_avatars : {name: "", is_lead: 0}
      //Set type name
      contract.type_name = this.getContractTypeName(contract.type)
      //Set delivery name
      contract.delivery_name = this.getProductCategoryName(contract.delivery)
      //Set status type
    }
  }
```

Comment: sometimes there is a weirdness with `console.log` - it can show a reference rather than a copy - to 100% see the current state that your `ContractList` is in either set breakpoints or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(contractsList / contract))`. If you are going to go with the `console.log` method make sure that if you have circular dependencies you use a `stringify` that can handle those

Comment: First, thank you for the review/edit. And you are right, I can't see "account_managers" attributes using stringify! So I guess, something is wrong when I add the array inside the object? I am gonna look through this, will require `[...arrayName]` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You probably have some async code fetching the ContractList ? It might be fetched during / after your call to contractList ? Without further code can't really help :D
If you want to I can look over it with Live Share (VSC extension)